# accessing a new vm's terminal without using the console in UI

Tags: vmware

I'm new to vmware and i'm trying to do some automation when creating a vm from an OVA file. Essentially, I have an OVA that I need to get into the console and run a script so I can get to it via the internet...the script is this (runs a netplan config and some iptable commands), I just don't know how to execute or run the commands manually without having to get into the UI via the console.

I'm just trying to figure out how I can run this without having to access the `console` via the vmware esxi UI.

I'm using packet.com's environment to provision a server with vmware esxi on it via terraform, and then use ansible to deploy a few ova's on it.

The problem then is though that I can't access the newly deployed vm's unless I go into the console of the vm via the UI. I'm trying to see how I can do that either via an api or some other fashion so I can do some further automation after the VM's come up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the VM has VMware Tools running, that would give you access to run a process/command/script in the Guest OS using the GuestProcessManager object in the vSphere Web Services API. More specifically, using the StartProgramInGuest method: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html#startProgram